# SwiftUI Slider, how to change a second variable

Tags: swift, swiftui, slider

At the moment my slider changes just my kms variable, but I would also like it to increase or decrease the price variable by the percentage variable for each step of the slider. Is there an easy way to implement this?
Thanks.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SliderStruct: View {
   
   @State var kms: Double = 100_000
   var kms2: Double = 100_000
   
   var price: Double = 5_000
   var percentage: Double = 0.05
   
   var body: some View {
       VStack{
           
           //increase price by percentage as kms decrease, decrease price by percentage as kms increase
           //price *= percentage, price /= percentage

           Text("$\(self.price, specifier: "%.0f")")
           
           Text("\(self.kms, specifier: "%.0f") Kms")
           Slider(value: $kms, in: kms2 - kms2...kms2 + kms2, step: 20_000)
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The question here is how to get two values from one slider.

Unfortunately, the slider provides only one value as there is only one handle:

[image: The slider with one handle]

So we can't get two values from it instantly. What we can do instead, is to get that one value and convert it to our two values using some formulas.

For the **kilometres** - the formula is pretty easy, it just multiplies the slider value to some coefficient.

For the **price** - the formula is slightly more complicated as we need to calculate percentages.

So, here is the final code with calculations. Please, check the comments that I add there to understand the solution better.

```swift
struct SliderStruct: View {

    /// This state stores slider value that is in the range from 0 to 10
    @State var sliderValue: Double = 5

    // Constants
    let kmsStep: Double = 20_000
    let pricePercentesStep: Double = 0.05

    // Computed properties

    /// Calculating kms by simply multiplying the slider value
    var kms: Double { sliderValue * kmsStep }

    /// Calculating the price using percentage formula
    var price: Double {
        // You might need to adjust the formula here,
        // as it wasn't super clear to me from the question
        // But I guess regularly percentes work like this
        5_000 * (
            1 + pricePercentesStep * (sliderValue - 5)
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("$\(self.price, specifier: "%.0f")")

            Text("\(self.kms, specifier: "%.0f") Kms")
            Slider(value: $sliderValue, in: 0 ... 10, step: 1)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is what we have as a result. Please, adjust the percentage calculation formula if I didn't understand it correctly from your description.

[image: The result of calculations derived from SwiftUI slider value]

Comment: Thank you very much. My question wasn't as clear as it should have been, but your answer was very informative. I did tweak the formula very slightly so that price reduced as the kms increased and vice versa.

Comment: @decibeljames would you be ok marking the answer as accepted If the works for you then?

Answer (score 0):

This was an interesting problem and something I've never tried before, so I took  quick attempt at solving it (kind of forced it to work!), but working with the constraints of the original question. Although, some information was still kind of vague.

```
class DistanceObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var kms: Double = 100_000
    var kms2: Double = 100_000
    var price: Double = 5_000
    var pricePlaceHolder: Double = 5_000
    var percentage: Double = 0.05
    private var oldValue: Double = 100_000 // set to initial kms
    func getPrice() -> Double {
        if kms.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 20000) == 0.0 {
            if kms != oldValue {
                if kms < oldValue {
                    price = price + (pricePlaceHolder * percentage)
                } else if kms > oldValue {
                    price = price - (pricePlaceHolder * percentage)
                }
                oldValue = kms
            }
        }
        return price
    }
    func setPrice(price: Double) {
        self.price = price
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var distance: DistanceObject = DistanceObject()
    var body: some View {
        let price_mod = Binding<Double>(
            get: { return distance.getPrice() },
            set: { distance.setPrice(price: $0) }
        )
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("$\(price_mod.wrappedValue, specifier: "%.0f")")
                Text("\(distance.kms, specifier: "%.0f") Kms")
                Slider(value: $distance.kms, in: distance.kms2 - distance.kms2...distance.kms2 + distance.kms2, step: 20_000)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I decided to go for the custom binding approach inside the ContentView, and have that binding perform the calculations in the ObservableObject class object. It is not the best solution, but this and the other answer should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have implemented some of your logic here and I now have the result I was after.